# Why wildcard matching in bash gets different results in bash and source?

Tags: bash

I have a script `case 11.2 in +([0-9])?(.+([0-9])))  echo aa;;   *)  echo bb;; esac`

While using `source test.sh` it prints `aa` but while using `bash test.sh` it returns an error

```
test.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 1: `case 11.2 in +([0-9])?(.+([0-9])))  echo aa;;   *)  echo bb;; esac'
```

An workaround is to use `bash -i`. But why they get different results in interactive and non-interactive mode?

Comment: @EDG956 No, that's a completely different topic.

Answer (score 2):

The extended glob patterns (`+(...)`, `?(...)`, `+(...)`, etc.) require the `extglob` shell option to be set. Add `shopt -s extglob` at the beginning of the script.